# XMLUnit - Comparing two XML responses

Tags: java, xml, junit, xmlunit

expectedResponseXml 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetResponse xmlns="http://whatever.co.uk/xsd/nam/message/GetResponse/">
    <Success>
        <Case>
            <Mort>M123456</Mort>
            <Appl>01</Appl>
        </Case>
        <Decision>D</Decision>
        <ProcessingRoute>R</ProcessingRoute>
        <Score>99999</Score>
    </Success>
</GetResponse>
```

and actualResponseXml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<GetResponse xmlns:ns2="http://whatever.co.uk/xsd/nam/message/GetResponse/"> 
    <ns2:Success> 
        <ns2:Case> 
            <ns2:Mort>M123456</ns2:Mort> 
            <ns2:Appl>01</ns2:Appl> 
        </ns2:Case> 
        <ns2:Decision>D</ns2:Decision> 
        <ns2:ProcessingRoute>R</ns2:ProcessingRoute> 
        <ns2:Score>99999</ns2:Score> 
    </ns2:Success> 
</GetResponse>
```

The error message is:

```
Expected child 'GetResponse' but was 'null' - comparing <GetResponse...> at /GetResponse[1] to <NULL>
```

Comparing code:

```
Diff myDiffSimilar = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(actualResponseXml))
                                        .withTest(Input.fromString(expectedResponseXml))
                                        .checkForSimilar()
                                        .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byName))
                                        .build();
```

I've tried everything from the official github account for XMLUnit and several stackoverflow similar questions to fix this error which I feel is a difference in namespace which should've being ignored by the differenceEngine. As from the above code, I compare the two xmls through their String representation. When I take out the `checkForSimilar()`, I get this error instead

```
Expected namespace uri 'null' but was 'http://whatever.co.uk/xsd/nam/message/GetResponse/'
```

My maven dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlunit-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any help will be seriously appreciated!

Comment: Their namespace is different : expectedResponseXml's `GetResponse` tag has a namespace `http://whatever.co.uk/.../GetResponse/` because it is defined as its default namespace (xmlns), while actualResponse defines a ns2 prefix for the same namespace but doesn't use it for the `GetResponse` tag, only for its children.

Comment: You have a namespace problem; in your expectedResponse, all elements are from the same namespace, in the actual one, GetResponse is default namespace and the others in `ns2`. Check how that happens.

Answer (score 0):

After fighting with this problem which those guys above rightly mentioned was a namespace issue, I discovered what the problem was.
when marshalling a jaxb object to XML, avoid using the QName(localPart) constructor as that gives unpredictable problems an issue that is known and mentioned in the documentation!

> In an XML context, all Element and Attribute names exist in the
>   context of a Namespace. Making this explicit during the construction
>   of a QName helps prevent hard to diagnosis XML validity errors. The
>   constructors QName(String namespaceURI, String localPart) and
>   QName(String namespaceURI, String localPart, String prefix) are
>   preferred. [link here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html)

Why it's there is a wonder to me!! Use

```
marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement(new QName(namespaceURI, localPart, NS_PREFIX), jaxbObject.getClass(), jaxbObject), outputStream);
```

on your marshaller to remove unwanted namespaces and set it to default.